# AJAX jQuery call not firing in IE7, IE8 but works fine in Firefox, Chrome, etc

Tags: wordpress, jquery

I have a custom WordPress plugin I made and it doesn't seem to work in IE7 or IE8. But works fine in IE9.

So the user clicks this link:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;color:#ddd;" onclick="Javascript:cp_module_lottery1ptentry();">LINK</a>
```

Which in turn calls this:

```
        function cp_module_lottery1ptentry(){
        cpdlotterymsg='<?php _e('Are you sure you want to use ', 'cplotto'); ?> <?php echo get_option('cp_lottery1_enter_amount'); ?> <?php _e(' points to purchase a '.get_option('cp_point_entry_label').'?', 'cplotto'); ?>'; 
        thebox = new Boxy('<form id="cp_donate" name="cp_donate" method="post" onsubmit="Boxy.confirm(cpdlotterymsg,function(){cp_module_lottery1ptentry_do();});return false;"><p><strong><?php _e('Use', 'cplotto'); ?> <?php echo get_option('cp_lottery1_enter_amount'); ?> <?php _e('points to purchase a '.get_option('cp_point_entry_label').'.', 'cplotto'); ?></p><br /><br /><input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Purchase '.get_option('cp_point_entry_label').'', 'cplotto'); ?>" style="width:300px;" /></form>', {title: '<?php _e(''.get_option('cp_point_entry_log_label').'', 'cplotto'); ?>', modal: true});
    }
```

Which works, but the next step it break where it calls: cp_module_lottery1ptentry_do()

```
        function cp_module_lottery1ptentry_do(){
        <?php $cb_current_page_url = get_permalink(); ?>
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: "action=cp_module_lottery1ptentry_do",
            success: function(data){
                if(data.success==true){
                    Boxy.alert(data.message);
                    window.setTimeout('window.location = "<?php echo $cb_current_page_url; ?>"', 5500);
                    thebox.hide();
                    thebox.unload();
                }
                else{
                    Boxy.alert(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I get no errors in IE7/IE8 just nothing happens when it calls the cp_module_lottery1ptentry_do() function.

I did a lot of searching and try several things but nothing is working.

Comment: Ummmm, what are we clicking on in your demo page? What demo account?

Comment: this code is aweful.. You have the same basic function like 30 times with only 1 thing slightly different.. Checkout $.extend function from jquery.. Also you can setup AJAX defaults http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/
Checked the source on your page, not the above..

Comment: Personally what I would do is get rid of the onclick attribute on the elements and bind them with unobtrusive javascript.. Also, then what I would do is put some custom attributes in the elements that are going to fire the ajax calls, perhaps make an action attribute that will have what the action you are passing (in the data param), then a cb parameter that defines the name of a function that will be called on success for a request

Comment: then you just need 1 function that will figure out what to pass to the backend, and what function to call on success.. You'll get rid of like 90% of that code

Comment: Sorry I'm not following everything you guys are saying. I'm still pretty new to jquery. Can you provide a example? On the demo account you can login using this. Username: demouser3 Password: demouser3

Comment: I would love to optimize my code more. So something like this? http://pastebin.com/u331K5K7 But back to my original query, any thoughts on why won't this work in IE7/IE8. Thank you for your replies thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things I changed to get it working. I changed the data to this:

```
data: {action: "cp_module_lottery1ptentry_do"},
```

Then the box variable I removed all html code:

```
thebox = new Boxy('<form name="cp_donate" id="cp_donate" method="post" onsubmit="Boxy.confirm(cpdlotterymsg,function(){cp_module_lottery1ptentry_do();});return false;"><label for="cp_points"><?php _e('Use', 'cplotto'); ?> <?php echo get_option('cp_lottery1_enter_amount'); ?> <?php _e('points to purchase a '.get_option('cp_point_entry_label').'.', 'cplotto'); ?></label><br /><br /><input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Purchase '.get_option('cp_point_entry_label').'', 'cplotto'); ?>" style="width:300px;" /></form>', {title: '<?php _e(''.get_option('cp_point_entry_log_label').'', 'cplotto'); ?>', modal: true});
```

So now it works, in IE6 - IE9! Here if the final code:

```
function cp_module_lottery1ptentry(){
cpdlotterymsg='<?php _e('Are you sure you want to use ', 'cplotto'); ?> <?php echo get_option('cp_lottery1_enter_amount'); ?> <?php _e(' points to purchase a '.get_option('cp_point_entry_label').'?', 'cplotto'); ?>'; 
thebox = new Boxy('<form name="cp_donate" id="cp_donate" method="post" onsubmit="Boxy.confirm(cpdlotterymsg,function(){cp_module_lottery1ptentry_do();});return false;"><label for="cp_points"><?php _e('Use', 'cplotto'); ?> <?php echo get_option('cp_lottery1_enter_amount'); ?> <?php _e('points to purchase a '.get_option('cp_point_entry_label').'.', 'cplotto'); ?></label><br /><br /><input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Purchase '.get_option('cp_point_entry_label').'', 'cplotto'); ?>" style="width:300px;" /></form>', {title: '<?php _e(''.get_option('cp_point_entry_log_label').'', 'cplotto'); ?>', modal: true});
```

}

```
function cp_module_lottery1ptentry_do(){
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "json", data: {action: "cp_module_lottery1ptentry_do"},
    success: function(data){
        if(data.success==true){
            Boxy.alert(data.message);
            window.setTimeout('window.location = "<?php echo $cb_current_page_url; ?>"', 5500);
            thebox.hide();
            thebox.unload();
        } else { Boxy.alert(data.message); }
    }
});
}
```

I also have a .js file which has this in it. Thank you for the ajaxSetup tip Matt Wolfe!

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ url: "../../../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", type: "POST", cache: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the your `admin-ajax` file is declaring the appropriate document type.

```
<?php header('Content type: application/json'); ?>
```